# Leaflet - onEachFeature mouseover update innerHTML of table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, leaflet

I am trying to add a mouseover event to my map:
The aim is to display some of the polygon properties in a table outside the map when I hover over them. But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? My JS knowledge is very poor, I thought it might work with a code like this:

```
<html>
...
<script>
    function mouseoverfunction(e) {
            var layer = e.target;       
            tableupdate(layer.feature.properties);
        }


    function mouseoutfunction(e) {
                 tableupdate();
        }


    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                mouseover: mouseoverfunction,
                mouseout: mouseoutfunction
            });


     tableupdate = function (props) {    
                    document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML = (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.NAME + '</b>' : 'Other Table Text');

</script>
       <table>
        <tr><td id="cell">Hello</td></tr>
       </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not far ...

layer.feature.properties is an object (an associative array)

To enumerate the properties, you need

```
var properties = e.target.feature.properties;
for (var prop in properties) {
   if (properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
      console.log("prop: " + prop + " value: " + properties[prop]);
   } 
}
```

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/wo8cm8mt/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was the right solution, but I just made a simple mistake, to fix it, I simply put the table  infront of the JS tableupdate function and made a simple adjustment and then it suddenly worked. Like this:

```
     <html>
    ...
    <script>
        function mouseoverfunction(e) {
                var layer = e.target;       
                tableupdate(layer.feature.properties);
            }


        function mouseoutfunction(e) {
                     tableupdate();
            }


        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: mouseoverfunction,
                    mouseout: mouseoutfunction
                });

    </script>

     <table>
            <tr><td id="cell">Hello</td></tr>
           </table>
    <script>
         tableupdate = function (props) {   
 document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML =  '<b>' + props.NAME + '</b>';

    </script>

    </html>
```